Failure to decode JSON
I'm trying to decode the following ZK proof, that lives in a JSON file, into a Solidity struct, using the Foundry book guide for JSON, but I'm getting continuous either errors or the wrong values:
proof.json (output from circom)

{
  "pi_a": [
   "2720399574835611047319432267519597443800510951793924100709604643916046668864",
   "21169447659913775869641616993668271312873067516271118167674241904778219813622",
   "1"
  ],
  "pi_b": [
   [
    "788356656035051841708358638450195352382615813361747425582051608449447866349",
    "21509538277609533773031757573429186661467719646375006140164215546123692163566"
   ],
   [
    "9028525878891699111734184918251721195102867864970556377714819801325638399258",
    "18633996315291794828222944575811265884401355999740084735365734766162700392691"
   ],
   [
    "1",
    "0"
   ]
  ],
  "pi_c": [
   "5581999086238776195409293931034667783461156042606193706354659978644098138906",
   "11656141149254556914721437054215616892710984578952823965610611542248660952601",
   "1"
  ],
  "protocol": "groth16",
  "curve": "bn128"
 }

1.- If I use this struct:
struct RootStruct {
    string curve;
    uint[2] pi_a;
    uint[2][2] pi_b;
    uint[2] pi_c;
    string protocol;
}

...it runs, but by logging pi_a[0] I get 224 instead of 2720399574835611047319432267519597443800510951793924100709604643916046668864, which I find weird that it runs since pi_a is of length 3 and not 2.
It's worth mentioning that when logging curve, it successfully logs bn128. But when trying to log protocol, it throws an empty string.
2.- If I use this struct:
struct RootStruct {
    string curve;
    uint[3] pi_a;
    uint[3][2] pi_b;
    uint[3] pi_c;
    string protocol;
}

...it reverts when decoding:
bytes memory data = vm.parseJson(json);
RootStruct memory rootStruct = abi.decode(data, (RootStruct));

Same result also for 1 and 2 if using bytes32 instead of uint.
3.- If I try:
uint[] memory x = vm.parseJsonUintArray(json, "pi_a");

..., it reverts with the error script failed: failed selecting from JSON: "path error: \n$pi_a\n^^^^^\n", but I'm logging the output of string memory json = vm.readFile(path) and it's the proper proof from proof.json, so that's working fine.

SOLUTION
The issue is happening because

parseJson handles all arrays as dynamic arrays
"90.." is treated as a string, and not a number.

So this can pe parsed into the following struct:
struct RootStruct {
    string curve;
    string[] pi_a;
    string[][] pi_b;
    string[] pi_c;
    string protocol;
}

And then you can convert strings to numbers by doing vm.parseUint(rootString.pi_a[i])
